# Spring Boot Async Transaction Rollback Issue

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-data-jpa, transactions, rollback

Facing 1 strange issue in spring boot @Async and @Transactional, following is sample code:

**ServiceA**

```
@Transactional
public ResponseA methodA() {
    try {
        // some code
        saveTableA() //save some data to tableA
        serviceB.methodB();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStacktrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

**ServiceB**

```
@Async
public void methodB() {
    try {
        // some code
        serviceC.methodC();
        save some data to tableB
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStacktrace();
        throw new ServiceException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**ServiceC**

```
public void methodC() throws Exception {
    try {
        // some code
        call to another service // this is failing sometime
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStacktrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

now in **methodC** there is some issue and exception occur, so I want to rollback data stored in **methodA**'s **saveTableA**, which is part of synchronous part.
Rollback is currently not happening.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Because you make `methodC` executes asynchronously with `methodA` , it is possible that when `methodC` throws exception , `methodA` already completed and committed the transaction.

If you want to relies on `@Transactional` to rollback, `methodA` have to complete after `methodC` . So there is no points to make `methodC` executes asynchronously if this is the case.

If you must make `methodC` to execute asynchronously with `methodA` , you have no choices but only can manually rollback by yourself . Start a transaction in `methodC` to undo what are done by `methodA` after you catch exception in `methodC`.

Comment: understands, seems valid thing to me. let me try the second suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your code like below

ServiceA:

```
@Transactional
public ResponseA methodA() {
    try {
        // some code
        saveTableA() //save some data to tableA
        serviceB.methodB();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

ServiceB:

```
@Async
public Future<?> methodB() {
    try {
        // some code
        serviceC.methodC();
        save some data to tableB
    } catch(Exception e) {
       return AsyncResult.forExecutionException(e);
    }
    return new AsyncResult<>(null);
}
```

Comment: it won't work. see my answer please